# Can viruses travel through pictures I took with my smartphone?

Tags: google, video, photos, iphone

I plan on uploading my photos/videos from my iPhone to my computer using a usb cable. I suspect that my iPhone may have a virus because I've been to questionable site on accident.

If I upload photos/videos I taken from my iPhone to my computer via usb cable is there a chance a virus can come through the connection?

Answer (score 4):

Sure they could, but it's unlikely.

Speaking generally - it's statistically almost impossible your iOS device was compromised on the OS level. The most likely price for a vulnerability on iOS 10 or iOS 11 would be 5 to 15 million dollars. That means run of the mill viruses can't afford them and would profit far more selling to governments and spy agencies which generally design and deploy them to never spread so they don't get discovered.

Unless you work for atomic power / weapons research or intelligence or some very powerful company / people, the odds you have a virus on iOS is low.

That being said, if you have sketchy apps, downloaded files or jailbroken devices it's quite possible your files could be compromised with run of the mill PC viruses and much less likely Mac malware and least likely Mac virus.

The steps you take to protect your computer could be as simple as enabling GateKeeper, only running signed apps, updating your Mac. If you want windows protection advice - you might ask that on https://superuser.com or from Microsoft.

Comment: You seem to have a very high opinion about the security level of iOS. Considering that Apple updates it ever so often, claiming it fixed ‘security issues’, I find that hard to believe. There are dozens found every week.

Comment: @Aganju For a consumer product, it's rather good that they actively find & fix instead of leaving it anguished. All [Apple](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-49/year-2017/Apple.html) product got 420 published security vulnerabilities to this date since 2017, while [Linux](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-33/year-2017/Linux.html) kernel alone got 389 to this date since 2017, we haven't include Debian, GNU, Canonical etc.

Comment: @Aganju I know for certain there are viruses and weaknesses in iOS - just that for monetary reasons, they are very narrowly deployed. Most of the "security" issues in the last year are not exploitable remotely, not virulent, and many are just denial of service / crashes as opposed to actual exploitable issues. I see the continual patching as a feature of iOS that other operating systems lag behind - especially Android, but also more computer based OS. The actual user adoption of updates is one of the best things about Apple and iOS from a security standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

iPhones do not get viruses, and if a virus was written for an iPhone, it would not run on a Mac or PC or any computer.

Comment: There are some compromising software but statistically speaking, the difference between a few compromised and no viruses is mostly academic. +1 in my book on the TLDR summary. I posted a little more context to help people decide what to do.